# Optimize print output where i use check on zero. Ruby

Tags: ruby

Currently, I'm having print like this

```
 print ((stamp_amount[0], 'first mark') unless stamp_amount[0].zero?), (', ' if !stamp_amount[0].zero? && !stamp_amount[1].zero?),
            ((stamp_amount[1], 'second mark') unless stamp_amount[1].zero?)
```

`stamp_amount` is an array with 2 integer values

Let's say in the current situation `stamp_amount[0] = 10` and `stamp_amount[1] = 3`

Output preview:

```
10 first mark, 3 second mark
```

So if `stamp_amount[0] = 0` the `10 first mark,` part won't be show. Same if `stamp_amount[1] = 0` the `, 3 second mark` part won't be shown

For me, it seems a little bit incorrect in terms of theory. Could you please suggest me the more correct or less painful print of this? :)

Cheers!

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? It _looks_ like it's trying to join two optional parts with a `', '`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `stamp_amount`?

Comment: "stamp_amount could be the only integer which is generated." - you may want to rephrase this. It's certainly not an integer and it's not generated in this snippet.

Comment: Done. @SergioTulentsev stamp_amount is an array with 2 integer values. As you can see there is 3 parts. Each having a check on zero, so if there is a value of zero it won't be shown. I will add a test output in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to join a sequence of up to two elements with a separator. The joining is a solved problem, see [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

The problem can be then reduced to "how can I produce the correct sequence, given my `stamp_amount` input". Now this can be done in a thousand ways. Here's one:

```
def my_print(stamp_amount)
  ary = [
    !stamp_amount[0].zero? && stamp_amount[0],
    !stamp_amount[1].zero? && stamp_amount[1],
  ].select{|elem| elem }
  
  ary.join(', ')
end

my_print([10, 3]) # => "10, 3"
my_print([0, 3]) # => "3"
my_print([10, 0]) # => "10"
my_print([0, 0]) # => ""
```

Here's another

```
ary = []
ary << stamp_amount[0] unless stamp_amount[0].zero?
ary << stamp_amount[1] unless stamp_amount[1].zero?

ary.join(', ')
```

Here's yet another. This version can handle `stamp_amount` of any length.

```
ary = stamp_amount.reject(&:zero?)

ary.join(', ')
```

I'd go with the third, but the second one may be the easiest to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `select`, as an alternative to `reject` (shown in part 3 of the answer by Sergio Tulentsev). It is just asa readable, and depending on the context and on the future changes to the code, you may prefer one versus the other.

```
puts stamp_amount.select{ |a| !a.zero? }.join(", ")
```

A few examples of inputs and outputs are:

```
stamp_amount   output
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
10, 3          10, 3
10, 0          10
0, 3           3
0, 0           (prints an empty line, because the selected array is empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating `zero?` on index points more often than is needed, but the first thing I would look at refactoring here is the readability of the code. It might be nicer to calculate the message to print outside of the print method and explain what is happening with variable names.

```
# rubocop is going to complain about variable assignment like this
first_amount, second_amount = *stamp_amount
```

We can actually use the reason rubocop prefers the `.zero?` over `== 0` or `.empty?` method to guide our development. `zero?` is in *essence* just `empty?` but it communicates the meaning of what you are attempting to do in a better manner. I would use this reasoning when assigning strings to variables that explain what they are doing.

```
some_name_that_explains_what_this_is_0 = "#{first_amount} piecu centu marka" 
some_name_that_explains_what_this_is_1 = "#{second_amount} tris centu marka"
```

Your current code is confusing as you have the possibility of printing a string like "10 tris centu marka" which does not make lexical sense and probably not what you are after considering tis evaluates to 'second mark', which would pose an issue if the first value is zero. We also could reject zero integers before we start converting them to strings.

```
array = [1, 0].reject(&:zero?)
```

Now we can take the array and do something like:

```
string = []
array.each_with_index { |e, i| string << "#{e} #{Ordinalize.new(i).ordinalize} mark" }
message = string.join(', ')
print(message)

# ord class
class Ordinalize
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def ordinalize
    mapping[@value]
  end

  def mapping
    # acounting for zero index
    ['first', 'second']
  end
end
```

where we are calculating the ordinalization and letting our new class handle the sentence structure for us.

Outputs:

```
[1, 0] => "1 first mark"
[0, 1] => "1 first mark"
[1, 2] => "1 first mark, 2 second mark"
```